# Parse a FlatFile with Multiline using BizTalk

Tags: biztalk, biztalk-2010, biztalk-2009, biztalk2006r2

My file contains data like:

```
First name:     ahmed 
Last name:  nasser
City:   giza
```

i created a schema to parse this file, but the element store all the line.. such as

```
<Fname>First name:  ahmed</Fname>
<Lname>Last name:   nasser</Lname>
```

i want the element to store only the value without the label
..to be like this:

```
<Fname>ahmed</Fname>
<Lname>nasser</Lname>
```

How To do that using Flate File Schema.. BizTalk?

Comment: Please provide your input file content with white chars. Is it "First name:\tahmed\r\nLast name:\tnasser\r\nCity:\tgiza" ?

Comment: As per FCR, please provide the exact file format and then we can help you.  Also provide the schema you have so far.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Biztalk Flat File Schema Wizard will help you. You can use this text file you copied into the question as "Instance file" (1. page of the wizard). Tell the wizard that this file is a delimited one (3. page of the wizard) and the delimiter is ":" (4. page of the wizard). On the 5. page of the wizard you can set the labels to be ignored and that's all.

If the records of the input flat file are present in one line, I think the best if you simply remove the labels from the file. You can do this by creating a custom pipeline component, using C# it is super easy. After removing the labels your file will consist of pure data separated by : , which is a good format for a flat file schema.

Comment: thanks Koszczi,
But when i use only the delimiter as ":"
the element store the value and the value of the next line of the file because i'm not using {CR}{LF}
so it store like:

    <Fname>  ahmed Last name</Fname><Lname> nasser E-mail</Lname><Email> ahmed@company.com City</Email><City> giza State/Region</City><State> cairo Country</State><Country> egypt Postal code/ZIP</Country>
and this is incorrect values

i want the values to be like this:
    <fname>ahmed</fname> <lname>nasser</lname> <email>ahmed@company.com</email> <city>cairo</city>

Comment: Do you mean the flat file does not contain line breaks so every record is present in one single line?